# What is the equivalent of UseOAuthBearerAuthentication in an ASP.NET Core 2 application?

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-2.0

I am upgrading a resource server that accepts access tokens from our oAuth server. In .NET 4.7, I had a startup configuration that looked like this:

```
appBuilder.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
```

When I add the Nuget Package 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth', I get a warning that the package is not compatable with the target .NETCoreApp. Makes sense, but I'm not sure what the new package is.

I thought the package I needed was 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth'. That allows me to add to startup:

```
services
     .AddAuthentication(OAuthDefaults.DisplayName)
     .AddOAuth("Bearer", options => options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "uhhh" );
```

Why would I be configuring an endpoint, I just want to look for an authorization token, not actually serve them up. This looks like the setup for an oAuth server, not a recipient. Also, the old 'OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions' class allowed me to override things like 'AccessTokenFormat' but I'm not seeing that in the new options.

Lastly, I see that there is the option to configure oauth this way:

```
app.UseOAuthAuthentication
```

But it complains that it's Obsolete, looks like a Core 1 version of 'AddOAuth', and nothing about AccessTokenFormat.

Any ideas?

Comment: What did you end up doing to solve this, some custom middleware to unprotect the tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core does not provide a direct replacement for those APIs or their associated token server. The current guidance is that you use a server like IdentityServer4 along with AddJwtBearerAuthentication.