# OAuth2 tokens in ASP.NET Core from our own authorization server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0

Currently we have a handful of web applications written in .NET Framework and use OAuth2 bearer tokens by using a shared machine key between our authorization server application and any web application that consumes the tokens like the following:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <machineKey validationKey="{VALIDATION_KEY}" decryptionKey="{DECRYPTION_KEY}" validation="SHA1" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Then in start up for web applications that consume the tokens we put the following:

```
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
```

That's it, then we're able to use OAuth2 bearer tokens from our authorization server in the particular web application. However we're building another API but in ASP.NET Core and we're wondering how to accomplish the same?

Comment: There is no direct replacement, see [What is the equivalent of UseOAuthBearerAuthentication in an ASP.NET Core 2 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47804064/what-is-the-equivalent-of-useoauthbearerauthentication-in-an-asp-net-core-2-appl)

Comment: So then the only option will be to write some custom middleware to unprotected the tokens? I can't imagine we're the only ones needing to consume our own tokens in this way, what BS.

Comment: In my opinion, the right way is using the machine key in both old and new asp.net core web api application, since its too old. Besides, there is no way to use machinekey inside the asp.net core. The only way is replace the old way in asp.net. Details about how to replace it, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/compatibility/replacing-machinekey?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: I've tried playing around with this but didn't get anywhere, can't find any examples of what I'm trying to accomplish or any real documentation on how to use Core's data protection feature to do something like this.